# cakePHP search function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

in the search function i have this piece of code

```
foreach($words as $word) {

            $search = '%'.$word.'%';

            $query['conditions'][]['or'] = array(
                'ProductComponent.codice LIKE' => $search,
                'ProductComponent.nome'.__('_it', true).' LIKE' => $search,
                'ComponentType.nome'.__('_it', true).' LIKE' => $search,
                'Material.nome'.__('_it', true).' LIKE' => $search,
                'Finish.nome'.__('_it', true).' LIKE' => $search,
                'ClientCode.client_component_code LIKE' => $search,
            );
        }
```

and when i execute the query i have this error

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column
>   'ClientCode.client_component_code' in 'where clause'
>   [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

this is the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_codes` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`product_component_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`client_component_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=225 ;
```

this is the ClientCode model

```
<?php
class ClientCode extends AppModel {
var $name = 'ClientCode';
var $belongsTo = array('ProductComponent', 'User');
}
?>
```

and these are the relations of the ProductComponent model

```
<?php
class ProductComponent extends AppModel {
var $name = 'ProductComponent';
var $belongsTo = array('ComponentType', 'Material', 'Finish','Line');
var $hasMany = array(
    'Part', 
    'RelatedComponent',
    'LineRelatedComponent' => array(
        'className'  => 'RelatedComponent',
        'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('LineRelatedComponent.line_id' => NULL)),
    ),
    'GenericRelatedComponent' => array(
        'className'  => 'RelatedComponent',
        'conditions' => array('GenericRelatedComponent.line_id' => NULL),
    ),
    'CustomPriceList',
    'PriceList',
    'ClientCode'
);
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Upload');
```

I don't understand why...PLEASE HELP. Thanks!

Comment: do you have `ClientCode.client_component_code` column in your database?

Comment: only the last condition doesn't work, the others work fine

Comment: yes Marek i have that column in my database

Comment: than clear your cache in /app/tmp (and all subfolders) and try again, otherwise, it's problem of your model definition/implementation

Comment: post both, model class and database table creating SQL sequence, and append it to your question, via link `edit` under it

Comment: In which of the controllers did you put this code? ProductComponent controller?

Comment: @Oldskool yes i put it in ProductComponent controller

Comment: I would suggest reading [this Bakery post](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/grant_cox/2008/06/23/get-the-find-query-sql-rather-than-query-result) and implementing that extension for the MySQL datasource. You'll then be able to do `$this->Model->find('sql', $options)` which will return the query in stead of executing it. You can then more easily debug the query.

If you do this, please add the query to your question to allow us to help you more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using containable? It sounds like you are trying to perform a condition on a non-joined table.